# ITIN received but original passport not received after 100 days. What to do?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, itin

Me and my daughter are dependents who got our ITIN in April, but did not get our passports back after 100 days.

We called the call center and got different answers at all times and twice they said it has been sent. Yesterday the customer care lady told me to ask the congressman of my place. Its been only 1 year since we came from India. My daughter is two.

We went to Bellevue IRS office but they did not help. We called taxpayer advocate but they said they don't take document missing cases. Now who is congressman of Bellevue Washington? Can he really get passports back? We can't get help from our embassy since the office is a 10 hour drive, and I don't think I have any original documents for myself and daughter. Hope to see reply. Worried to even call customer care since July.

Comment: IRS seem to be in deep $#!+ since they've changed the rules last year.... Re congressman - here: http://www.house.gov/representatives/find/

Comment: A question like this has already been answered here. Please see the answer at: [ITIN application rejected, and IRS lost one of our passports. How to get back the lost passport?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23156/itin-application-rejected-and-irs-lost-one-of-our-passports-how-to-get-back-th)