# How do I get my passport back from the IRS?

Tags: united-states, irs, itin

The IRS has had my passport for 120 days, and I haven't gotten it back. When I call them, they ask me to wait. I have to go somewhere soon and my visa status needs to be changed too. What should I do? Will they give me letter saying they have lost it so that I can apply for the new one?

I have asked them about this several times and every time they reply saying "I'm sorry ma'am but we can not do anything in this matter" and when I ask them to give me the location or phone number of the IRS office in Austin, they say "We cannot do that."

Comment: Why does the IRS have your passport? Since you mentioned Austin, I presume you're applying for an ITIN. If that's the case, have you seen [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/23156/7590)?

Comment: Yes, I have already seen that question. I m worried about for long should I wait? Because every time, they say it is 30 days and they would do something about it. I m afraid that what if my original passport arrives the day I file for new one.

Comment: Thanks for replying. They have my passport because i had applied for itin no.

Comment: @user11095 if original arrives the day you file for new one - you just surrender the original to your consulate. It will be cancelled anyway.

Comment: oh okay.......But all my visa stamps are there on the original one. It will be a whole lot of trouble again when traveling. i hope to get my passport really soon.